# Eclipse type mismatch errors on same wildcard

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, wildcard

I'm doing an assignment that requires me to implement skip lists and binary search trees. I'm also supposed to implement iterators for each data structure.

The skip list and binary search tree is implemented using generics K and V.

```
public class SkiplistMap<K extends Comparable<K>,V> implements SortedMap<K,V>
public class SkiplistMapNode<K extends Comparable<K>,V>
public class BSTMap<K extends Comparable<K>,V> implements SortedMap<K,V>
public class BSTMapNode<K extends Comparable<K>,V>
```

The iterators only use the comparable type, so I plugged in ? as the non comparable type.

```
public class SkiplistMapIterator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterator<T> {

    SkiplistMap<T,?> list;
    Queue<SkiplistMapNode<T,?>> queue;
    int version;

    public SkiplistMapIterator(SkiplistMap<T,?> sl){
        list = sl;
        queue = new LinkedList<SkiplistMapNode<T,?>>();
        SkiplistMapNode<T,?> N = sl.getHead();
        while (N != null){
            queue.add(N);
            N = N.getNext()[0];
        }
        version = sl.getVersion();
    }

    public void remove() throws UnsupportedOperationException{
        if (queue.isEmpty()) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No element present");
        else {
            T toRemove = queue.remove().getKey();
            SkiplistMapNode<T,?> N = list.getHead();
            while (N != null){
                if (N.getNext()[0].getKey().compareTo(toRemove) == 0){
                    SkiplistMapNode<T,?> found = N.getNext()[0];
                    for (int l = list.getLevel()-1; l >= 0; l--){
                        N.getNext()[l] = N.getNext()[l].getNext()[l];
                        found.getNext()[l] = null;
                    }
                    list.incVersion();
                    break;
                }
                N = N.getNext()[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My problem:** correctness of the code aside, when I try to make two `SkiplistMap` or `SkiplistMapNode` objects point to each other, Eclipse freaks out screaming there's a type mismatch. It tells me

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from SkiplistMapNode<T,capture#16-of ?> to SkiplistMapNode<T,capture#15-of ?>
```

But I'm typing in the same question mark, so I'm not sure why Eclipse hates it. Can anyone explain it in dummy terms? I've tried "typing" the method but it's giving me even more errors.

Comment: "But I'm typing in the same question mark" - yes but that question mark stands for "some specific, unknown type", so two question marks (also known as wildcard captures) aren't guaranteed to match. See [the Java Tutorials article on wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) for an intro.

Comment: Can you show us the line where this error occurs? (And possibly some of the surrounding code, IF it could be relevant for the problem - e.g. if it contains relevant variable declarations)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** It's not guaranteed that two `?` wildcards are the same type. If it was, the `?` would be a nonsense, because that's why they are: for representing an unknown type. 
**2.** Look at the types that should be converted. 'Capture#15 of ...' and 'Capture#16 of ...' seem to be two different things.

Answer (score 0):

How many question marks do you think there are in java?

Every occurrence represents an unknown type, so the compiler has to assume they are all different.

Give your "don't care" type a name, even if it has no constraints.